# Mapping values between data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Records:-

 UniqueID      Country        Price
    AAPL         USA            107
    AAPL         USA            105
    GOOG         USA            555
    GOOG         USA            555
    VW           DEU            320

Mapping:-

 UniqueID      Country        Price
    AAPL         USA            120
    GOOG         USA            550
    VW           DEU            300
```

I want to add a column Final and map the values from the mapping table to the records tables . For e.g. all the AAPL entries in the records table should have a final value of 120.

```
Output:-

Records:-

 UniqueID      Country       Price     Final
    AAPL         USA          107        120
    AAPL         USA          105        120
    GOOG         USA          555        550
    GOOG         USA          555        550
    VW           DEU          320        300
```

I used the following line of code:-

```
Records$Final <- Mapping[which(Records$UniqueID==Mapping$UniqueID),"Price"]
```

It throws me an error saying the replacement and data length are different. Also using **merge** duplicates the columns, which I don't want to.

Comment: look up the `merge` function

Answer (score 3):

We can use `inner_join`,

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(records, Mapping, by = c('UniqueID', 'Country'))
#  UniqueID Country Price.x Price.y
#1     AAPL     USA     107     120
#2     AAPL     USA     105     120
#3     GOOG     USA     555     550
#4     GOOG     USA     555     550
#5       VW     DEU     320     300
```

To follow your method then,

```
Records$Final <- Mapping$Price[match(Records$UniqueID, Mapping$UniqueID)]
Records
#  UniqueID Country Price Final
#1     AAPL     USA   107   120
#2     AAPL     USA   105   120
#3     GOOG     USA   555   550
#4     GOOG     USA   555   550
#5       VW     DEU   320   300
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in the Mapping table rename the column Price to Final

```
colnames(Mapping)[colnames(Mapping) == "Price"] <- "Final"
```

Then, use merge(). You should be getting what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
Records=data.frame(UniqueID=c("AAPL","AAPL","GOOG","GOOG","VW"),country=c("USA","USA","USA","USA","DEU"),Price=c(107,105,555,555,320))

Mapping=data.frame(UniqueID=c("AAPL","GOOG","VW"),country=c("USA","USA","DEU"),Price=c(120,550,300))

names(Mapping)[3] <- "Final"

Output <- merge(x=Records,y=Mapping[,c(1,3)],by="UniqueID",all.x=TRUE)
```